# Can rotate a polygon painted in a JPanel, but can't rotate a polygon nested in a JPanel inside this JPanel

Tags: java, paintcomponent

If I paint a Polygon onto some JPanel container and put rotation on a timer, it works fine. However, if I paint a Polygon onto a JPanel, and then try to rotate the Polygon, it does not rotate. The Polygon coordinates are changing, and the JPanel (seems) to be repainting, but it just won't rotate. Here's some sample code of what I mean. I know there are also a bit more bugs I need to work out but I'm only concerned with getting the Polygon on the JPanel to rotate.

```
package PolygonRotateTest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class PolygonRotateTest {

    static ConvexPolygon polygon;
    static Timer t;
    static Model m1;
    static JPanel container;
    static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Small compiler issue with "no enclosing instance of type PolygonRotateTest is in scope"
        //because I lazily copy-pasted critical classes into one to make this more convenient.
        //Should still run fine if you ignore the warning.

        //ConvexPolygon makes a pentagon centered at (300,200) with a radius of 100
        polygon = new ConvexPolygon(new Coordinate(300, 200), 100, 5);

        //Model extends JPanel, accepts a polygon.
        m1 = new BallModel(polygon, Color.red);

        //Draws the polygon on the container
        container = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.fillPolygon(polygon);
            }
        };

        t = new Timer(1000 / 60, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                m1.rotate(Math.toRadians(1));
                container.repaint();
                m1.repaint();
                //Rotates the polygon 60 times per second.
                //Drawing the black polygon directly onto the container rotates correctly
                //However, the model (m1) does not redraw/rotate the red polygon
                //despite using the same polygon.

            }
        });
        t.start();

        container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(container);
        container.add(m1);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    ///Other stuff begins here///////////////
    public static abstract class ActorPolygon extends Polygon {

        private Coordinate center;

        public ActorPolygon(Coordinate center) {
            this.center = center;

        }

        public void rotate(double radianIncrement) {


            for (int i = 0; i < npoints; i++) {
                Coordinate rotate = rotatePoint(new Coordinate(xpoints[i], ypoints[i]), radianIncrement);

                xpoints[i] = rotate.getX();
                ypoints[i] = rotate.getY();

            }


        }

        public Coordinate rotatePoint(Coordinate c, double radianIncrement) {

            double xDist = c.getX() - getCenter().getX();
            double yDist = c.getY() - getCenter().getY();

            Coordinate rotated = new Coordinate(
                    (int) (0.5 + center.getX() + xDist * Math.cos(radianIncrement) - yDist * Math.sin(radianIncrement)),
                    (int) (0.5 + center.getY() + xDist * Math.sin(radianIncrement) + yDist * Math.cos(radianIncrement)));

            return rotated;
        }

        @Override
        public void translate(int dx, int dy) {
            super.translate(dx, dy);
            int x = center.getX() + dx;
            int y = center.getY() + dy;
            center = new Coordinate(x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String output = "";
            output += "Center at " + center + "\n";
            output += "contains " + npoints + " points" + "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < npoints; i++) {
                output += i + " " + "(" + xpoints[i] + "," + ypoints[i] + ")" + "\n";
            }
            return output;
        }

        public Coordinate getCenter() {
            return center;
        }

        @Override
        public abstract ActorPolygon clone();
    }

    public static class ConvexPolygon extends ActorPolygon {

        private int radius;

        public ConvexPolygon(Coordinate center, int r, int n) {
            super(center);
            this.npoints = n;
            this.radius = r;
            xpoints = new int[npoints];
            ypoints = new int[npoints];
            double radianIncrement = 2 * Math.PI / npoints;
            double shift = Math.PI / npoints - 3 * Math.PI / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < npoints; i++) {
                xpoints[i] = getCenter().getX() + (int) (radius * Math.cos(i * radianIncrement + shift));
                ypoints[i] = getCenter().getY() + (int) (radius * Math.sin(i * radianIncrement + shift));
            }

        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        @Override
        public ConvexPolygon clone() {
            return new ConvexPolygon(getCenter(), getRadius(), npoints);
        }
    }

    public abstract class Model extends JPanel {

        private ActorPolygon original;

        public Model(ActorPolygon polygon) {
            this.original = polygon;
            this.setPreferredSize(original.getBounds().getSize());
            Rectangle bounds = polygon.getBounds();
            this.setBounds(bounds);

        }

        public ActorPolygon getActorPolygon() {
            return original;
        }

        public void rotate(double increment) {
            original.rotate(increment);
        }

        public void drawModel(Graphics g) {

            Rectangle bounds = getActorPolygon().getBounds();
            this.setBounds(bounds);
            this.setPreferredSize(this.getBounds().getSize());
            ActorPolygon shiftedPolygon = getActorPolygon().clone();
            shiftedPolygon.translate(
                    -1 * getActorPolygon().getCenter().getX() + (int) bounds.getWidth() / 2,
                    -1 * getActorPolygon().getCenter().getY() + (int) bounds.getHeight() / 2);
            g.fillPolygon(shiftedPolygon);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            drawModel(g);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String output = original + this.getSize().toString() + "\n" + this.getLocation() + "\n";
            return output;
        }
    }

    public static class BallModel extends Model {

        private Color color;

        public BallModel(ConvexPolygon p, Color c) {
            super(p);
            color = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void drawModel(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(color);
            super.drawModel(g);


        }
    }

    public static class Coordinate {

        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile, do you have a working version? I tried to edit it myself but it would require me to change several things.

Comment: It should throw an error but it still works if you ignore the warning.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Warnings and errors are different. The only reason it's working is because you have a past version of it that compiled and it's using that version when you run it. Any changes you've made since you didn't have any errors in your build will not show up. Test with a simple "Hello world" print statement at the beginning to check if it displays despite the compilation error.

Comment: Yea it works. I just made the assumption all IDE's can compile through errors though (I believe this is not the case now)

Comment: You can use the `Graphics2D.rotate(...)` methed or the `AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(...)`. Also it doesn't look to me like you ever change the angle of rotation.

Comment: Doesn't the Graphics2D rotations only rotate the graphics and not the actual Polygon points?